# how merge list and keep values with linq

Tags: c#, linq, merge

```
code    name     number    case
 1       a         5        1
 2       b         9        1
 1       a         6        1
 3       c         8        1
 2       b         1        1
 1       a         1        2
 2       b         3        2
 3       c         1        1
```

if case is 1 => number+=number , and if case is 2 number-=number and i want create this list with linq

for example
first in Third row code is 1 and case is 1
number Third row plus with number first row , number =11

in sixth row cod is 1 and case is 2 then number subtract , number=10

```
code    name     number    case
 1       a         10       1
 2       b         7        1
 3       c         9        1
```

Comment: You make no mention of the data structure this is in.  This is a simple group and sum but to answer your question correctly, we need to see the code you've made so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
var result = dataList.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(grouping => new
{
     Id = grouping.First().Id,
     Name = grouping.First().Name,
     Number = grouping.Sum(x => x.CaseId == 2 ? -x.Number : x.Number)
});
```

Comment: if i have a condition in my list what to do like this, i have case Column , if case is 1 number + and if case is 2 number -

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: i have a case Column plus code name number,if case is 1 value of number sum and case is 2 number Subtract and finaly grouping,It was clear?

Comment: No, it's not clear. Can you edit question with expected input & output?